# Creating an XML file using a Mapbox TMS

Tags: xml, mapbox, raster, qgis

I'm looking for a way to display a Mapbox map in QGis in so it's recognized as a raster layer.

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321251/open-a-mapbox-map-in-qgis), and I succeeded adding the TMS layer via TileLayer Plugin, using my mapbox url like this:
https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/styles/v1/[my_username]/[map_ID]/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=[my_access_token]

The problem is, adding a layer in this way is not recognized by QGIS as a raster layer, and I need to perform some raster operations on it.

On the other hand, I tried to create an XML file like this:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="TMS">
        <ServerUrl>https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/styles/v1/[my_username]/[map_ID]/tiles/256/${z}/${x}/${y}?access_token=[my_access_token]</ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>18</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

but it's not working.

Using the exact same XML with the Google TMS url `http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}`
 works ok.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/285391/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the XML file I was trying to import to QGIS was already correct. 
Using the GDAL command

```
gdalinfo --debug on mapboxTMS.xml
```

returned a coherent output.

Also, using the command gdal_translate resulted in a correct extraction of an area, which was exactly the raster operation I wanted to perform. In my case I used it like this:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 1499373.73124 3010255.99556 1499925.16592 3009716.74729 -of GTiff mapboxTMS.xml result.tif
```

So the problem actually seems to be on the QGIS side. According to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/285824/120964) it is probably caused by the GDAL WMS driver not working properly with QGIS.